# Moving Image up to align with slider?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have a simple slider on my site and am trying to get the image placed next to it aligned to the top. I can't seem to get it to do anything but align right or left for some reason. Check it out live www.bwsurfshop.com -- When I say aligned to the top, I mean the top of the slider so they are inline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been stuck on this one too long..

Comment: add `float:left` to .metaslider. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
.metaslider.metaslider-flex.metaslider-1439.ml-slider 
{
    float: left;
}
```

to the styles.css and changing

```
a img.alignright 
{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
```

}

to

```
a img.alignright 
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0 20px 20px;
```

}

should make the two images appear on the same line.

Comment: -Claps- Bravo, seems I need to brush up on my css. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, feel free to make the answer as correct so other people who have the same problem as you, will know how you solved your problem

Comment: I added some more content, now these two images are doing the same thing but don't seem to find a problem with the .img in css. Any thoughts? Again www.bwsurfshop.com

Comment: It is because the margin on the image makes it too wide for two of them to be on the same line.